# Confused by a combination of globbing, variable substitution and find command in bash

Tags: bash, find, sh, quoting, string-substitution

I am trying to pass a quoted globbing pattern to find command in script using variable. Does not work without eval. Is it a way to do this without eval?

First I use the followin command:

```
find . -name '*a*'
```

It works OK and produces the following output:

```
./AaA
./dir1/aaa.tst
./dir1/zabc1122333.tst
./dir2/dir3/zabc1122333.tst
./yyy/AaA
./zabc1122333.tst
```

Now I want to use a variable in place of quoted glob pattern '*a*'.

This does not work:

```
A='*a*' ; find . -name $A
```

It produces:

```
find: zabc1122333.tst: unknown primary or operator
```

The following four commands do not work either. They produce nothing:

```
A="'*a*'" ; find . -name $A

A=\'\*a\*\' ; find . -name $A

A=\'*a*\' ; find . -name $A

A='\*a\*' ; find . -name $A
```

Finally it works with eval:

```
A=\'\*a\*\' ; eval find . -name $A

./AaA
./dir1/aaa.tst
./dir1/zabc1122333.tst
./dir2/dir3/zabc1122333.tst
./yyy/AaA
./zabc1122333.tst
```

Is it possible to do it without eval?

Comment: You should read chapter "QUOTING" of "man bash".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use quotes (`"`) to prevent bash from globbing.

```
A='*a*'; find . -name "$A"
```

Look at the output of the following two commands.

```
A='*a*'; echo find . -name $A
```

and

```
A='*a*'; echo find . -name "$A"
```

Comment: Yep. Quotes go *around* data, not *in* data.